# Flex, AS3: Bind Width and Height of Component

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, mxml

```
<forms:InfoClass xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                 xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                 xmlns:forms="ph.com.alliance.iportfolio.forms.*" 
                 xmlns:ip="ph.com.alliance.iportfolio.controls.*"    
                 styleName="info" width="{mWidth}" height="{mHeight}">
```

**InfoClass.as**:

```
[Bindable] protected var mWidth:Number = 400;
[Bindable] protected var mHeight:Number = 200;
```

I set the container width and height using Bindable, now the problem is that when I change the value of the variables on initParam, it's not reflecting on the container.

Is there anyway that I can change this variable on `initParam()`?

Tried it, but the width and height are still not reflected, I only get the default values. The thing is all the other binded variables are working just fine. So my question is: Is this even doable? If it is, how can I do this?
Already browsed the net for any workaround, just not sure what to search.. Any ideas?

Comment: It wont work that way, you need to put those parameters inside the component creating instance of InfoClass.

Comment: hmm i thought so too.. i was working on 3 different views for mobile compatibility.. so i need to have a condition for the 3... the nasty solutions that I have was a shorthand if notation during declaration of the width and height.. :D

Comment: if all of your 3 views going to use same width and height then use a single tone class with binded parameters and use them.

Comment: i meant 3 different views for different dpi's 160, 240, 360.. I can't use the auto scaling feature as it will make my app unreadable or difficult to use on some tablets and mobile devices, so i have no choice but to go this route.

Comment: Where have you defined initParam() ?